# What is an algorithm to split a group of items into 3 separate groups fairly?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have this problem in my textbook: 
Given a group of n items, each with a distinct value V(i), what is the best way to divide the items into 3 groups so the group with the highest value is minimIzed? Give the value of this largest group.

I know how to do the 2 pile variant of this problem: it just requires running the knapsack algorithm backwards on the problem. However, I am pretty puzzled as how to solve this problem. Could anyone give me any pointers?

Answer: Pretty much the same thing as the 0-1 knapsack, although 2D

Comment: Since it came up and disappeared, here is an example of greedy failure {100, 51, 49, 40, 30, 20, 10}. Optimal answer is perfect split, greedily applying biggest unassigned element to smallest group isn't.

Comment: I have the same textbook.  Brian Dean gave it to me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tough homework problem. This is essentially the optimization version of the 3-partition problem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem

It is closely related to bin packing, partition, and subset-sum (and, as you noted, knapsack). However, it happens to be strongly NP-Complete, which makes it a harder than its cousins. Anyway, I suggest you start by looking at dynamic programming solutions to the related problems (I'd start with partition, but find a non-wikipedia explanation of the DP solution).

Update: I apologize. I have mislead you. The 3-partition problem splits the input into sets of 3, not 3 sets. The rest of what I said still applies, but with the renewed hope that your variant isn't strongly np-complete.

Comment: @RichieLi Honest question: How much detail do you want for me not to spoil the problem? i.e. Is the desired recurrence relation too much (not that I have it, I'd have to work it out myself)?

Comment: Huh, I'll try to work it out myself. It's due in the evening, so I'll get back to you if I need more help.

Comment: Actually, I have a question: In the 3 partition problem, how do you know which items you've already used?

Comment: Oops. I just re-looked at the definition of 3-partition. I have mislead you. However, if you are looking at tracking which numbers are still available, you can use a simple array with 0,1,2,3. Alternatively, use 4 hashsets for unassigned, set 1, set 2, and set 3. Alternatively, keep sorted lists for each of the 4 (or use heap-based data structures).

Comment: Update: I've got a dynamic programming solution. I can provide more hints if you need it. If you want a huge hint (possible spoiler), these lecture notes on subset sum basically give you everything you need: http://sites.cs.queensu.ca/courses/cisc365/Record/Week06/20111018.html

Comment: I've scrawled an O(SUM^2*N) algorithm on paper, I'm going to try it out now.

Comment: I've been refreshing periodically to see if you added a question. I'm guessing your algorithm worked. Congratulations.

Comment: Did you even take a look at 3-Partition problem? 3-Partition is NPC in strong sense, but this problem statement is weakly NPC problem, means there is a pseudopoynomial time algorithm for it.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: To paraphrase you, Did you even take a look at the response you commented on? Not only did I update the response (30 minutes after posting, 6 months before your comment) to state it was *not* 3 partition, but I provided a link to a reference that does have the information on how to solve the problem via dynamic programming.

Comment: @ccoakley, Yep, You fixed it, but edit your answer and remove wrong part. Similar question asked again today, and someone linked it to this, and I read first paragraph of your answer, actually it wasn't important to me how to solve it, it was important to see a correct answer and close new question.

Answer (score 1):

Let f[i][j][k] denotes whether it is possible to have **value j** in the first set and **value k** in the second set, with the **first i items**.

So we have `f[i][j][k] = f[i-1][j-v[i]][k] or f[i-1][j][k-v[i]]`.

and initially we have `f[0][0][0] = True`.

for every `f[i][j][k] = True`, update your answer depends on how you defines **fairly**.

Comment: But the ith item could alternatively go into the 3rd set, so I think it should be `f[i][j][k] = f[i-1][j-v[i]][k] or f[i-1][j][k-v[i]] or f[i-1][j][k]`.

Comment: Also, just to spell it out, when considering the solution for some i, j, k where f[i][j][k] = True, you would calculate the weight of the 3rd set using s[i] - j - k, where s[i] is the sum of the weights of the first i items (precomputed in linear time at the start).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "The Best" mathematically speaking, but one obvious approach would be to build a population of groups initially with one item in each group. Then, for as long as you have more groups than the desired number of final groups, extract the two groups with the lowest values and combine them into a new group that you add back into the collection. This is similar to how Huffman compression trees are built.

Example:

```
1 3 7 9 10
becomes
4(1+3) 7 9 10
becomes
9 10 11(1+3+7)
```

Comment: We haven't learned about this yet, so I don't quite think I should use this on this problem.

Comment: Picking nits: The greedy approach is optimal in the huffman case (for variable length encoding of fixed alphabets). It performs reasonably for partition only if the numbers in the problem are distributed nicely (where I can't be more precise than the word "nicely"). Given that the question was tagged "dynamic-programming", I would guess that the purpose of the assignment was not to use a greedy technique.