# Ideas to solve the following

Tags: algorithm

In a library there are `N` books with the number of pages in `i`<sup>th</sup> book given by `b_i`.These books are to be distributed among `K` students such that the difference between the largest sum of pages in the books assigned to any student and the smallest sum of number of pages in the books assigned to any student is minimum for the given input. Also the books are arranged in a certain order and this order must never be changed.

For example:

suppose `B[]` contains the number of pages in each book.

Then for `N=6` `K=3` `B={3,7,8,2,6,4}`, the output will be `0` as we can give book 1 and 2 to student 1 and book 3 and 4 to student 2 and the remaining to student 3. That makes 10 pages for student 1 10 for 2 and 10 for 3 and thus the difference is 0

similarly when `B={3,6,8,2,6,4}` then the minimum difference will be 1 .

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: I don't care if it's homework. This feel like an NP problem to me, and if it's not, I'd love to know an elegant solution. It feel a little like the subset sum problem, but we don't even know the sum we are looking for in advance. On the other hand, it's an ordered set, so that might help. Of course, this should probably be moved to: cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762230/what-is-an-algorithm-to-split-a-group-of-items-into-3-separate-groups-fairly

Comment: it isn't homework! it is a Directi final interview question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea for a greedy `O(nklogk)` algorithm to start you off. First, sort the books from largest to smallest. Then take the largest unassigned book and assign it to the kid with the least total pages. Keep doing this until all the books are assigned. Each book assignment requires you to sort the kids based on their total number of pages.

Comment: You can't sort the books from largest to smallest: "Also the books are arranged in a certain order and this order must never be changed."

Comment: That's silly. You can always take the book information, parse it, figure out which books goes where, and then assign it to the kids in order.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying here. It was my understanding that you have to assign the books to the students as blocks. For example, you can't get book 1,2, and 7. You must get every book in a range. So, you need to use ALL the books in the entire set, and each student must get all the books in *book* order. So, student 1 MUST get books [1,x1), student 2 *must* get books [x1, x2), and so on. You might be right, I'm just not understand your algorithm.

Comment: Without the limitation of maintaining the book's ordering, this is an NP-complete problem. With it, it's a DP problem.

Comment: aquinas is right. the the students should be alloted the books in blocks only. the order cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

w=sum of page's in B and you should calculate w/n to find limited for answer.if w/n is integer that means you have a this problem.is there x elements that sum of them equal to w/n.this seems NP problem's